Can you use Mi-Phone assistant to export notes from Mi-Cloud to PC?
I'm still looking to find a way to export my notes from my Redmi-9A to my PC with all images intact.
I recently found out about this program and I'm asking if I log into the cloud with it, can it access my 1000+ synced notes and mass-download them to PC with the notes and the images in them 100% healthy?
The program hasn't been updated since 2021 October though according to the site.
Program in question: https://miuirom.org/updates/mi-pc-suite
Any tips welcome!
